# Bootstrap in IE8 How to make some styling work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I found out that I need to make use of `Respond.js` if I want to make Bootstrap work in IE8. Once included, everything looks well, except one thing. It seems like HTML5 elements style won't adjust (even when editing with inline-code when using developer tool in IE11 (with emulation on IE8) within my local html file, but when I do the same on a [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/), it seems to work perfectly fine though).

Changing the HTML from:

```
<footer>...</footer>
```

To

```
<footer style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: tomato">...</footer>
```

works within the example page (while editing within the browser), but does not work when I open my local file and do the same thing.

Why can I add styling to a footer on the HTML5 elements within [the example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) page but not on my local file? Am I missing some file or do I need to do something differently? How can I make my `<footer>` styling work?

One suggestion I would do is making it just a `<div>` element with a class `.footer` but this is not the way it looks like within the Bootstrap example, so I do not know if this is the right way to fix the problem I am experiencing.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support most HTML5 functions. See here https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-8.html what is supported in IE8.

Comment: @C0dekid.php I am aware of this, but when I look at the Bootstrap example, changing inline code does appear to work, why is this then?

Comment: They have javascripts to make some of the HTML5 elements work on older browsers. Maybe you missing them

Comment: I can't believe that over 2% of people still use IE6/7/8 (according to SitePoint, 2016). That's disgusting. Anyway, this resource may be helpful for you: http://www.telegraphicsinc.com/2013/10/using-bootstrap-3-with-internet-explorer-8-ie8/

Comment: @C0dekid.php Could you refer me to any documentation concerning the use of this javascript code you are trying to tell me? Or should I be fine using the code of the answer below and not expect any issue?

Comment: @AaronLavers I agree but I leave that topic for discussion somewhere else. I will take a look at your resource link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 has a whole bunch of new elements for adding semantic meaning to your pages. For instance, `nav` signifies a navigational menu.

Since IE8 doesn’t know anything about these, it won’t recognize styles applied to them via CSS. Fortunately, there is an easy way to fix this by simply appending missing elements to the DOM of the page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
      document.createElement('header');
      document.createElement('nav');
      document.createElement('section');
      document.createElement('article');
      document.createElement('aside');
      document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Obviously you don’t have to define every HTML5 element in existence, just the ones you actually use. By the way, this code uses [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)s, a feature introduced by Microsoft to specifically support differences in browser versions.

Another important thing to point out is that HTML5 elements are displayed as `block` by default, but IE8 doesn’t know that either. To mitigate this issue you could either specify `display: block;` when styling specific elements or do it wholesale in your CSS:

```
header, nav, section, article, aside, footer {
   display:block;
}
```

Note that if you’re using an HTML5 aware reset stylesheet (like [this one](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)), this is probably already taken care of for you.

---

> Other way to use js liberaries

There are work-arounds in the form of the [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) polyfill scripts. Use one of these libraries to add support for HTML5 tags to old IE versions.

Comment: This looks kind of what I am looking for, though I still wonder, is this the way Bootstrap made the CSS work for the example pages? Can I read more about that somewhere (do you have a source for me)?

Comment: this way or by using js libraries i mentioned in my updated answer because when it comes to browser support you have to find a solution may be of creating a tags or just using libraries to support all tags...i'll give you a link if i find a source for u

Comment: Just adding `html5shiv` solved the problem for me. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template Shows this aswell.